# what is the Difference between start-pointers and interior-pointers and when to use these

Tags: c++, c, c++11

Difference between start-pointers and interior-pointers and in what situation we should prefer one over other?

Comment: I have never heard of interior-pointers. Where did you hear these names?

Comment: If [interior_ptr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0fh545k(v=vs.80).aspx) is what you're talking about, please update the tags to [c++-cli] (remove C, C has no such concept).

Comment: @Redx I was going through following doc which is meant for C only: http://es.gnu.org/~aleksander/valgrind/valgrind-memcheck.pdf

Comment: If you read the whitepaper you posted under introduction -> pointers; It explains which is which... What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Maybe he meant "smart pointers" and "inferior pointers"? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a complete guess, a "start-pointer" is a pointer returned by `malloc` or `new[]`, whereas an "interior-pointer" is a pointer to the middle of the allocation.

If so, then the important difference is that you need to `free` the start-pointer, not an interior-pointer.

This isn't terminology from the standard, though. "Interior pointer" usually means a pointer into some larger block of memory and I guess/deduce the rest. So, you probably need to provide the context. What book/course/interview is the question from?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Steve Jessop's answer is a correct answer that a start-pointer is a pointer returned by malloc(), etc. And an interior-pointers are pointers to places within that allocation. I cannot improve on his answer, but I will expand on it:

As an example, you might need up to a few thousand instances of some struct as a linked list. Instead of calling malloc() for the struct (or class) as needed, you call malloc() just once to allocate enough for a few thousdand instances. Then you create a free-list (a linked-list of the free instances). You can use and free by moving the instances (moving by adjusting the pointer-links) between the free-list and use list(s). Then, when the program no longer needs any of the instances of the struct, you call free() just on the start-pointer, the one originally returned by malloc().

I came across another definition of interior-pointer in the context of Windows and C++ programming for .NET Windows here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8901/An-overview-of-interior-pointers-in-C-CLI.

In C++ / .NET, an interior-pointer can also mean a pointer to memory in CLI heap, i.e. .NET's managed memory. However, seems to me that it is fundamentally the same idea. With using C++ and C with .NET's manages memory, I suppose we are not concerned with starter-pointers because we will never call free() to deallocate. .NET does the garbage collection for us.